# How to add type parameter's methods to a type that uses proxy

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, es6-proxy

I'm developing a simple RPC client/server library for my internal use. I would like to use one interface to describe both client and server, so I can share them between server and browser in my universal application.

The server is easy, the service simply extends my Service class and implements an interface describing the API.

The client will be implemented as an ES6 proxy, simply sending all method calls to the server, I'd like to have it strongly typed as well as the service class. *I need instances of type ServiceClient to have all methods and properties of it's type parameter, regardless of what is it.*

I was thinking about this syntax:

```
interface Api
{
    foo(): boolean;
}

class MyService extends Service implements Api
{
    public foo(): boolean { return true; }
}

// usage
let result = (new ServiceClient<Api>()).foo(); // type of result is inferred, I get an error if I try to use an undefined method, arguments are type checked...
```

I've tried to browse some typings where it works similarly, but couldn't find a way. Thank you for your help.

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: How to make ServiceClient<T> "inherit" methods from T, without actual inheritance and the need to implement them.

Comment: It seems that your code is missing some parts, what's `Service` and what's `ServiceClient`? Please share all of the code that is needed.

Comment: @NitzanTomer I don't know what to put into ServiceClient, except for my Proxy implementation (which is irrelevant), that's my question. Service is just a common parent type, it's empty at the moment, though in the future, it'll hold a constructor that registers it with the HTTP server.

Comment: Basically I need to somehow modify the type that's created when I call "new" - compile-time, it should stay normal at runtime.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're trying to do. You can't change something in compile time but not in runtime. Generics also are not included at runtime, so if you want `ServiceClient` to implement `Api` then just have the class implementing that interface. Can you please edit your question and be more specific about what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I don't know how to be more specific. I need the class ServiceClient<T> to dynamically "inherit" methods from T. I can't create a class implementing the interface because 1) that's what I'm trying to avoid, I'd have to pointlessly repeat myself and 2) it's handled by a proxy, not by an implementation of the interface, so any implementation would be incorrect.

Comment: @NitzanTomer I've edited the question, I hope it's more specific now.

Comment: @Tom if you've gotten a good answer to your question since this time, I would be interested to know.  I'm doing basically the exact same thing, but I can't even compile without stubbing the methods out on my class.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understand what you're asking.

You can't use the generics argument (`T`) in runtime so you can't dynamically create a proxy object which implements all of the methods in `T`.

What you can do is something like this:

```
interface Api {
    foo(): boolean;
}

abstract class Service {}

class MyService extends Service implements Api {
    public foo(): boolean { return true; }
}

const myService = new MyService();
const ServiceClient = {} as Api;
for (let key in myService) {
    if (typeof myService[key] === "function" && key !== "constructor") {
        ServiceClient[key] = function() {
            return myService[key].apply(myService, arguments);
        }
    }
}

let result = ServiceClient.foo(); // true
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Api%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20foo()%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aabstract%20class%20Service%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MyService%20extends%20Service%20implements%20Api%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20foo()%3A%20boolean%20%7B%20return%20true%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20myService%20%3D%20new%20MyService()%3B%0D%0Aconst%20ServiceClient%20%3D%20%7B%7D%20as%20Api%3B%0D%0Afor%20(let%20key%20in%20myService)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(typeof%20myService%5Bkey%5D%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22function%22%20%26%26%20key%20!%3D%3D%20%22constructor%22)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ServiceClient%5Bkey%5D%20%3D%20function()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20myService%5Bkey%5D.apply(myService%2C%20arguments)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20result%20%3D%20ServiceClient.foo()%3B))

What I did was created an instance of `MyService`, then I created an object which will be the proxy for this `myService`, this proxy `ServiceClient` is created as an empty object at first.
Then I iterate over the properties of the `MyService` instance and for each function (which isn't the constructor) I create a function with the same name on the proxy object, when each of this function is invoked then the equivalent function in `myService` is invoked.

---

#### Edit

If I understand, then all you need to do is to tell the compiler that your instance is of type `Api`:

```
class ServiceClient {
    // implement proxy magic here
}

let client = new ServiceClient() as any as Api;
let result = client.foo();
```

That should do the trick, as it creates an instance of the class that proxies things, and then tricks the compiler into thinking that this is an instance of `Api`.

Comment: But the ServiceClient class should not be tied to the Api interface. I don't need any support in runtime, my only point is to have strong typing. The ServiceClient class will contain an ES6 Proxy that will observe for any method calls, and proxy them to the server via a socket. I need a way to make ServiceClient instance that has methods and properties of any interface I specify as its type parameter.

Comment: The code I'm creating will be used as an external library, where the user will supply only the interface that describes the API and the service class, that handles server side, but nothing more.

Comment: I need "new ServiceClient<T>()" to create an intersection type of "ServiceClient & T", so I can use methods from T and compiler enforces strong typing, both on its return type and arguments.

Comment: That's not possible in typescript. You can only have interfaces for that. But if you want a class (that you can instantiate) then you need to know all of the methods up front.

Comment: I;ve created a function: "function createClient<T>(): JsonRpcServiceClient & T { return (new JsonRpcServiceClient()) as JsonRpcServiceClient & T; }" that does what I need. Surely there's no way to do this using the "new" keyword, as this adds an unnecessary layer of execution into my application?

Comment: You just keep confusing me. What is this `JsonRpcServiceClient`? and how exactly can you be sure that it implements `T`? Please edit you question and add all of this information, include all classes/function/what not so that it will be clear what you have and what you want to have

Comment: The ServiceClient's constructor creates an ES6 proxy that intercepts all method calls, so no method is undefined, everything is sent to the server. Since I, the developer (sadly not the type system), know that I will always implement only the interface I have, nothing more and nothing less, I want the usage of the client class strongly typed, since I have the interface that describes what the server supports available.

Comment: The class **HAS TO** implement nothing from the interface, or it would modify the behavior of the proxied class.

Comment: Hopefully I understand what you want, check my revised answer.